How to close the menu with framer motion while navigating to a different route
I have a project with nextjs and using framer motion to animate my menu when i click on a link to navigate on a new route about, contact etc.. I want the menu to close to give the smooth feeling on navigating to a different route
when I was using gsap I used to reverse the animation based on the isActive
is there is a way to achieve the same with framer motion ?
i just want the menu to close while navigating to a new route and that's it
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isActive) {
      tl.current.play()
    } else {
      tl.current.reverse()
    }
  }, [isActive])

and here is my current code
   'use client';
import { Content } from '@prismicio/client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import Hamburger from './hamburger';
import Nav from './nav';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

type NavProps = {
  nav: Content.NavDocument;
};

const Menu = ({ nav }: NavProps) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsActive(false);
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <>
      <Hamburger isActive={isActive} setIsActive={setIsActive} />
      <AnimatePresence mode='wait'>{isActive && <Nav nav={nav} />}</AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;

should mention that I have an exit animation for my nav but that only triggers if i exit the menu not when i click on a link to go to a different route
and here is my nav component
import { Content } from '@prismicio/client';
import { PrismicNextLink } from '@prismicio/next';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { menuSlide, opacity } from '../animation';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Curve from '../curve';
import Arrow from './assets/svg/arrow.svg';
import styles from './nav.module.scss';

type NavProps = {
  nav: Content.NavDocument;
};

const Nav = ({ nav }: NavProps) => {
  return (
    <motion.nav id={styles.nav} className='fixed bg-blur' variants={menuSlide} initial='initial' animate='enter' exit='exit'>
      <div className={styles.nav__container}>
        <div className={styles.nav__body}>
          <ul className={styles.nav__pages}>
            {nav.data.page.map(({ link, label }, index) => (
              <motion.li className={styles.nav__page} key={label} custom={index} variants={opacity} initial='initial' animate='enter' exit='exit'>
                <PrismicNextLink className={clsx(styles.nav__link, 'font-cairo')} field={link}>
                  <div className={styles.nav__dot}>
                    <span className={styles.nav__arrow}>
                      <Arrow />
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  {label}
                </PrismicNextLink>
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <span className='font-sm'>أين تجدنا</span>
          <ul className='font-sm'>
            {nav.data.social.map(({ link, label }, index) => (
              <motion.li key={label} custom={index} variants={opacity} initial='initial' animate='enter' exit='exit'>
                <PrismicNextLink className='font-sm link' field={link}>
                  {label}
                </PrismicNextLink>
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </ul>
          <ul className={clsx(styles.nav__social, 'flex-between')}>
            {nav.data.social.map(({ link, label }, index) => (
              <motion.li key={label} custom={index} variants={opacity} initial='initial' animate='enter' exit='exit'>
                <PrismicNextLink className='font-sm link' field={link}>
                  {label}
                </PrismicNextLink>
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Curve />
    </motion.nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;

